# How to deal with the error "vtkTrivialProducer :This data object does not contain the requested extent"?

Tags: c++, vtk

I wrote a code to read a *.mhd* file and cut a plane of it then display the plane in the window.
I have tested my code, it has already read the file successfully. And when the code runs to `renderWindow->Render()`. The code crashes.
It tells that:

> vtkTrivialProducer (010DD148): This data object does not contain the requested extent.

My environment is win7 64 bit,vtk 6.2 .
Here is my code:

```
#include <vtkSmartPointer.h>
#include <vtkRenderWindow.h>
#include <vtkRenderWindowInteractor.h>
#include <vtkRenderer.h>


#include <vtkImageData.h>
#include <vtkImageMapper3D.h>
#include <vtkImageCast.h>
#include <vtkMetaImageWriter.h>
#include <vtkMetaImageReader.h>
#include <vtkImageMandelbrotSource.h>

#include <vtkImageActor.h>
#include <vtkSmartPointer.h>
#include <vtkMatrix4x4.h>
#include <vtkImageReslice.h>
#include <vtkInteractorStyleImage.h>
#include <vtkMetaImageReader.h>
#include <vtkImageCast.h>
#include <vtkLookupTable.h>
#include <vtkImageMapToColors.h>
//TestingImage：..\\data\\brain.mhd
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
const std::string filename = "D:\\vtk\\Examples\\Chap05\\data\\brain.mhd";
vtkSmartPointer<vtkMetaImageReader> reader =
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkMetaImageReader>::New();
reader->SetFileName(filename.c_str());
reader->Update();



int extent[6];
double spacing[3];
double origin[3];

reader->GetOutput()->GetExtent(extent);
reader->GetOutput()->GetSpacing(spacing);
reader->GetOutput()->GetOrigin(origin);

double center[3];
center[0] = origin[0] + spacing[0] * 0.5 * (extent[0] + extent[1]);
center[1] = origin[1] + spacing[1] * 0.5 * (extent[2] + extent[3]);
center[2] = origin[2] + spacing[2] * 0.5 * (extent[4] + extent[5]);

static double axialElements[16] = {
    1, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 1, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 1, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 1
};

vtkSmartPointer<vtkMatrix4x4> resliceAxes =
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkMatrix4x4>::New();
resliceAxes->DeepCopy(axialElements);
resliceAxes->SetElement(0, 3, center[0]);
resliceAxes->SetElement(1, 3, center[1]);
resliceAxes->SetElement(2, 3, center[2]);

vtkSmartPointer<vtkImageReslice> reslice =
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkImageReslice>::New();
reslice->SetInputConnection(reader->GetOutputPort());
reslice->SetOutputDimensionality(2);
reslice->SetResliceAxes(resliceAxes);
reslice->SetInterpolationModeToLinear();

vtkSmartPointer<vtkLookupTable> colorTable =
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkLookupTable>::New();
colorTable->SetRange(0, 1000);
colorTable->SetValueRange(0.0, 1.0);
colorTable->SetSaturationRange(0.0, 0.0);
colorTable->SetRampToLinear();
colorTable->Build();

vtkSmartPointer<vtkImageMapToColors> colorMap =
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkImageMapToColors>::New();
colorMap->SetLookupTable(colorTable);
colorMap->SetInputConnection(reslice->GetOutputPort());

vtkSmartPointer<vtkImageActor> imgActor =
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkImageActor>::New();
imgActor->SetInputData(colorMap->GetOutput());

vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderer> renderer =
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderer>::New();
renderer->AddActor(imgActor);
renderer->SetBackground(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);

vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderWindow> renderWindow =
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderWindow>::New();
renderWindow->AddRenderer(renderer);
renderWindow->Render();
renderWindow->SetSize(640, 480);
renderWindow->SetWindowName("ImageResliceExample");

vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderWindowInteractor> renderWindowInteractor =
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderWindowInteractor>::New();
vtkSmartPointer<vtkInteractorStyleImage> imagestyle =
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkInteractorStyleImage>::New();

renderWindowInteractor->SetInteractorStyle(imagestyle);
renderWindowInteractor->SetRenderWindow(renderWindow);
renderWindowInteractor->Initialize();
renderWindowInteractor->Start();

return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's that `SetInputData()` does not set a pipeline connection. When you use it, you need to make sure that the pipeline that produces the data is manually updated. So adding a `color->Update();` or `map->update();` before rendering happens will fix the issue.

If your intention is to setup a pipeline connection such that any changes in filter parameters are automatically reflected in the viewer, use this instead:

```
imageViewer->SetInputConnection(color->GetOutputPort());
```